# Vue.config.js - creating a single main.js file and serve it from /static/

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I try to archieve something similar to this repo (https://github.com/glin/shiny-react-example) with the Vue CLI:

This is the webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  output: {
    // Serve the bundle from /static
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 4000,
    // Proxy everything besides the bundle to Shiny
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000'
      },
      '/websocket': {
        target: 'ws://localhost:3000',
        ws: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The index.html file contains the main.js file which gets passed via the proxy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shiny + React example</title>
  {{ headContent() }}
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" />
  <script src="static/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Running this in the commandline outputs this:

```
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /static/
× ｢wdm｣: Hash: d186059ee270d10260ab
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 263ms
Built at: 2020-07-25 15:38:16
  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  372 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
```

In this repo there is no `/static/` path, so I guess the dev server/webpack creates it under the hood? It just works fine.

I tried to rebuild this with the `vue.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
  },
  publicPath: "/static/",
  devServer: {
    port: 4000,
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        target: "http://localhost:3000"
      },
      "/websocket": {
        target: "ws://localhost:3000",
        ws: true
      }
    }
  },
```

transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"]
};

But when I run `npm run serve`, I get this:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:4000/static/
  - Network: http://192.168.0.27:4000/static/
```

In the browser I get: `http://localhost:4000/static/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

This seems to get handled differently here. How can I archieve the same as in the react example?